# With CentOS 6 and LXC, "ifconfig" is unable to see network interface (but busybox "ifconfig" works fine)

Tags: linux, networking, virtualization, ifconfig, lxc

I've just started working with LXC under CentOS 6 (via the libvirt adapter).  If I create an LXC container, I'm unable to see any network interfaces when using the native system tools:

```
# ifconfig -a
#
```

The behavior is very odd; specifying an interface by names yields neither the expected output nor an error message.  This is true even for clearly invalid interface names, like this:

```
# ifconfig foo
#
```

The `ip` command exhibits the same behavior.

On the other hand, if I use "ifconfig" provided by [busybox](http://busybox.net/), everything works as expected:

```
# busybox ifconfig -a

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:E0:12:C8  
          inet6 addr: fe80::5054:ff:fee0:12c8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:268 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:17814 (17.3 KiB)  TX bytes:552 (552.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

So...what does busybox know that the native tools don't?  The libvirt config for this environment is pretty standard; the network definition looks like this:

```
<interface type='network'>
  <mac address='52:54:00:e0:12:c8'/>
  <source network='default'/>
  <target dev='veth0'/>
</interface>
```

The full configuration is [here](https://gist.github.com/1321297) if you think it might help.

I'm running:

- lxc-0.7.2-2.el6.x86_64
- kernel-2.6.32-71.29.1.el6.x86_64

**EDIT**

Weirder and weirder...it's a display issue, not a functionality issue.  I can see the output of `ifconfig` if I pipe it into anything, so for example:

```
# ifconfig eth0 | cat
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:E0:12:C8  
          inet addr:192.168.10.10  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5054:ff:fee0:12c8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:573 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:37914 (37.0 KiB)  TX bytes:552 (552.0 b)
```

And in fact even when not piping the output, `strace` shows that `ifconfig` is in fact writing the output to file descriptor 1 (aka `stdout`), so it's not clear why no output is actually showing up.  This could be either an LXC or a `virsh` issue, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this kind of thing happens which the apparently-failing program is trying to *smarter*, by querying the terminal driver for its size when it's set incorrectly or just 0 (look at stty -a), or using terminfo but with an incorrect $TERM or $LC_* variables (try running env), or in some weird cases where some buffer is getting used that's swallowing data that doesn't fill the buffer.  Running strace on ifconfig vs the busybox version might be interesting.   The normal Linux ifconfig is really spare about this kind of thing - about all it does is an access to the locale info.